# How to assign variable inside of the string in php?

Tags: php, xml

I wanna store sql query in XML and execute it by php.

the problem is that i need to assign variable inside of string from XML but i don't know how to do this.

here is example.

XML

```
<data>
    <test> select * from table where testdata = $testdata;
    </test>
</data>
```

.

PHP

```
$xml_string = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/data.xml');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);

$sql = $xml->test;

//here is the problem. variable $testdata is not recognized in the string
$testdata = "test";

$result = $this->conn->query($sql);

$data = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

can anyone let me know how to fix the problem? and i am also open to new suggestion to store or handle sql queries thanks.

Comment: $testdata = "test"; use quotes

Comment: @AkshayP fixed it. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<data>
    <test> select * from table where testdata = '%s';
    </test>
</data>
```

Then:

```
$result = $this->conn->query(sprintf($sql, 'test'));    
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: it works thanks ! but i am worried if there is a couple of variables inside of string then it must be confusing.

Comment: No at all, please take a look at `sprintf` function doc [http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).